# Can't Build Even New Projects after Upgrading Flutter

Tags: flutter, build, upgrade

I am developing Flutter projects using vscode. After upgrading Flutter from 3.10 to 3.16.3 using the flutter upgrade command, when I create a new project, I get the following message:

```
[test_project] flutter create --template app --overwrite .
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Creating project ....
Resolving dependencies...
Got dependencies.
Wrote 129 files.

All done!
You can find general documentation for Flutter at: https://docs.flutter.dev/
Detailed API documentation is available at: https://api.flutter.dev/
If you prefer video documentation, consider: https://www.youtube.com/c/flutterdev

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd .
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in .\lib\main.dart.

exit code 3221225501
```

When I try to build the project for windows, I get the following:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
i:\soft\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(248,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'I:\work\flutter-projs\test_project\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\7e7530df3ca3759e8b25d8281e0718c2\flutter_windows.dll.rule;I:\work\flutter-projs\test_project\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\2fbfa67e692ef0c565297c7533a2d0cf\flutter_assemble.rule;I:\work\flutter-projs\test_project\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [I:\work\flutter-projs\test_project\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.

Exited (-1073741795).
```

Flutter Doctor found no issues.

I think the problem first manifests itself when it tries to download the sky_engine package after "flutter upgrade". This is the output:

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
Downloading package sky_engine...                               exit code 3221225501
```

I tried removing the windows folder in the project as well as commands such as flutter clean, dart pub cache repair, dart pub cache clean, but it still doesn't work. What is wrong and what can I do to get rid of the exit code 3221225501 problem and make my projects build successfully? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Open the **Command Prompt** and Run

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Then enter `y` to accept all licenses

Comment: I fixed every issue flutter doctor found but the problem persists.